# Is there a way to overcome clipping in FAB button?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I'm working on animating the drawable of a [FAB](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html). The animation makes the part of the drawable twice as big. However, once is starts growing, it is clipped under the layout of the FAB:

[image: FAB in question]

Is there a way that I can avoid this clipping?

It's placed in a CoordinatorLayout, so it isn't possible to place an ImageView on top of FAB, and make it look like there's only one item.

Also, it is not possible to edit `clipChildren`property, since that property is related to ViewGroup, and this is only a View.

Here's the layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    tools:context="com.example.aleksandar.rasporedcasova.MainActivity">

    [other contents of CoordinatorLayout]

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/bluetooth_drawable_animated" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try `android:clipChildren="false"` on the parent layout? also please provide your layout

Comment: That property is not available for Views, only ViewGroups. I've added the layout.

Comment: this is why I said *on the parent layout*

Comment: Actually, is this even related to the FAB? It might as well be that the drawable contents are going off the boundaries _of the drawable itself_...

Comment: I've tried adding to the parent layout, and it doesn't work :(